# Send And Get ID from tables using PHP while looping

Tags: php, html-table

I need your help.
I have tables using PHP while looping
and I need help on how to get the id from selected rows in the tables and then send it to another page. I need to do this because the tables do not view the details so I need that ID to view the details or query from full tables.

The following is my code

```
<?php

include('config.php');
session_start();

$table = "select * from rekuest";
$select = mysql_query($table);

$user = $_SESSION['username'];
?>
<head>
        <title>Home</title>
        <link href="css/960.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
        <link href="css/defaultTheme.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
        <link href="css/myTheme.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
        <script src="js/jquery-1.6.1.js"></script>

    <script src="js/jquery.fixedheadertable.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/demo.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css" media="screen"> 
        #tombol {
            display: block;
            width: 90px;
            height: 30px;
            background: url(img/tombol_normal2.png) no-repeat top;
        }
        #tombol:active {
            background: url(img/tombol_pressed.png) no-repeat bottom;
        }
    </style> 

</head>
<body>
<h1 align="center">List All Of Request</h1>
<h2 align="center">Welcome, <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></h2>

<form>
    <input type="button" name="new" value="New Request" align="right"
    onClick="window.location='form.php'"/>
    <input type="button" onClick="window.location = 'logout.php?exit=yes'" class="myButton" value="Logout"/>

</form>
<div id="divider">
</div>

<table width="900" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="myTable04">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No Reff</th>
            <th>Subjek Request</th>
            <th width="20px">Permintaan</th>
            <th>Waktu</th>
            <th>Jenis Request</th>
            <th>Customer</th>
            <th>Sifat Requirement</th>
            <th>Pelaksana</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Respon</th>
            <th>Rekomen</th>
            <th>Nama File</th>
            <th>Attachment</th>
            <th>Detail</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($select)) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['id_rekuest']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['subjek']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['permintaan']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['waktu']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['jenis']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['customer']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['sifat']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['pelaksana']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['status']; ?></td>
            <td><?php  ?></td>
            <td><?php  ?></td>
            <td><?php  ?></td>
            <td><?php  ?></td>
            <td><a id="tombol" style="cursor:pointer" onClick="window.location='detail.php'"></a></td>
        </tr>

    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't 100% know what you're asking, but I think what you want is to pass the id to the detail page. You could do this via a get with the following:

```
<td>
    <a id="tombol" style="cursor:pointer" href="detail.php?id=<?php echo $row['id_rekuest']; ?>"></a>
</td>
```

And then use $_GET['id'] (sanitized, please!) to query the database for anything based on that id

Comment: thanks alex, yes you're right exactly for the answer, and thanks a lot to repair my post. i'm very nubie in this forum and php

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
<td><a id="tombol" style="cursor:pointer" onClick="window.location='detail.php'"></a></td>
```

I would put

```
<td><a id="tombol" href="detail.php?id=<?php echo $row['id_rekuest']; ?>">Details</a></td>
```

Then, in detail.php you can get the id from `$_GET['id']`.

Comment: Just an aside, instead of `<?php echo $var; ?>` you can also use `<?= $var ?>`.

Comment: thanks for your help, thanks a lot, its very important to me as nubie in php programming